# MVC 4. Using filterContext.HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated check

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

Im have a custom filter; void IActionFilter.OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext) on the POST: /Account/Login of my AccountController. 
While I can get the username being authenticated I cannot seem to get if the user is authenticated. I tried this:

```
    if (!filterContext.HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
    {
        triedstatus = "Not authenticated";                
        // return RedirectToAction("LogOn", "Account");
    }
    else
    {
        triedstatus = "Authenticated";
    }
```

But I wonder if the authenticated / found in db or not information is available in aOnActionExecuting filter. Any ideas please?

Comment: Are you using Forms Authentication? And how come you can't get if the user is authenticated? It's a boolean property

Comment: Why are you doing this in an Action Filter?  If you need to do something based on Authorizaiton, you should use an Authorization Filter.